# Read values into an array fails

Tags: c

I want to use a function to `scanf` up to 10 values for an array with the size 10, and also keep track of the number of values that are in the array because I'll need it later for solving some maths about the array, (max value, min value, etc.).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int enter(int MeasurmentData[], int nrOfmeasurments)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i) 
    {

        int MeasurmentData[10];
        scanf("%d",&MeasurmentData[i]);

        int nrOfmeasurments = 0;
        nrOfmeasurments ++;
        return nrOfmeasurments;

     }

int main()
    {
    int MeasurmentData[10];
    int nrOfmeasurments;
    char menuoption;

    while (1) 
    {
        printf("Measurment tool 2.0\n");
        printf("v (View)\n");
        printf("e (Enter)\n");
        printf("c (Compute)\n");
        printf("r (Reset)\n");
        printf("q (Quit)\n");

        printf("enter your option:\n");
        scanf(" %c", &menuoption);

        if (menuoption =='e') \\ enter values
        {
            int MeasurmentData[10];
            int nrOfmeasurments;

            enter(MeasurmentData, nrOfmeasurments);

        }
        else if(menuoption == 'v') \\\ view values
        {
        //printf("%d", MeasurmentData[]);
        }
        else if(menuoption == 'c')
        {

        }
        if(menuoption == 'q')
        {
        printf("Exiting Measurment tool 2.0\n");
        return 0; 

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program it should print Measurment tool 2.0, after the the user has the choice of inputting e(enter) which will scan in up to 10 values into an array, if the user clicks q(quit) while in the enter option already he will be returned to the main menu where he can do whatever.

V(view) prints out the array for the user so that he can view what elements are inside.

C(compute) uses the elements inside and the nr of elements to calculate the highest value element, lowest.

Comment: Welcome! But what is your question? As a new contributor you might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are re-defining `MeasurmentData` within the scope of your for-loop.  You probably don't want to do that.

Comment: you mean before scanf? is it enough to have it in the parameter of the enter function?

Comment: Weather vane, it doesnt work and i wonder if my functions are wrong

Comment: Yes, before the `scanf`.  You are creating a local variable of that name rather than working with the one passed in as an argument.

Comment: You still have not asked a question, or read the links I suggested. What is it supposed to do, what is the input, the expected output and the actual output? Saying "it does not work" isn't useful information.

Comment: How about the int nrofmeasurments? have i written so that everytime a value is put into the array it also adds +1 to nrofmeasurments which is 0 in the beginning

Comment: the program is supposed to scan up to 10 values in an array and also keep track of how many values are in the array, this by using functions which i am new to, I do not know if i have defined the function right or if i am calling upon it correctly either

Comment: Sadly, the posted code generates many compiler errors.

Comment: Please provide us with some input and expected outputs. Also provide us with the actual outputs as well.

Comment: You should remove the line `int MeasurmentData[10];` from your function. it is masking the argument that was passed to the function. There is only one iteration of the loop too, due to `return`.

Comment: John, when i run the program it should print Measurment tool 2.0, after the the user has the choice of inputting e(enter) which will scan in up to 10 values into an array, if the user clicks q(quit) while in the enter option already he will be returned to the main menu where he can do whatever. V(view) prints out the array for the user so that he can view what elements are inside. C(compute) uses the elements inside and the nr of elements to calculate the highest value element, lowest.

Comment: I see a few misunderstandings on how `c` works. It is hard to point at *the* error when everything in your program is "weird". The good thing is that you seem to have mastered "Hello World". But I recommend to reread whatever comes after that in your `c` textbook.

Comment: Please fix your indentatin. Then you will see that `main()` is defined inside `enter()`. This make me think that this cannot be a [mre] or you have some very strange environment.

Comment: regarding; `return nrOfmeasurments; }`  this is missing a closing brace '}' before the `return;` statement

Comment: per the code logic,  If the user enters 'e' and some values, then 'q' then enters 'e' again, all the prior values will be lost

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your code. Ill try to explain. You have over declared your variables too many times. And since you have a fixed loop you don't need to count the measurements you will always read 10 measurements.

Below are the code with some modifications. Feel free to ask anything about it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXIMUM_MEASURMENT 10

int enter(int MeasurmentData[])
{   
    char input[100];
    int nrMeasurement = 0;

    // reseting Measurment data
    for(int i=0;i<MAXIMUM_MEASURMENT;++i) MeasurmentData[i] = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<MAXIMUM_MEASURMENT;++i) 
    {
        scanf("%99s", input);
        if(strcmp(input, "q") == 0) {
            break;
        }
        MeasurmentData[i] = (int) strtol(input, (char **)NULL, 10);
        nrMeasurement++;
    }

    return nrMeasurement;
}

void showMeasurments(int* MeasurmentData, int length) {
    int i = 0;

    printf(" ======== Measurment ======== \n");

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", MeasurmentData[i]); 
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int MeasurmentData[MAXIMUM_MEASURMENT];
    int nrOfmeasurments;
    char menuoption;

    while (1) 
    {
        printf("Measurment tool 2.0\n" "v (View)\n" "e (Enter)\n" "c (Compute)\n" "r (Reset)\n" "q (Quit)\n enter your option:\n");

        scanf(" %c", &menuoption);

        if (menuoption =='e') // enter values
        {
            enter(MeasurmentData);
        }
        else if(menuoption == 'v') // view values
        {
            // show
            showMeasurments(MeasurmentData, MAXIMUM_MEASURMENT);
        }
        else if(menuoption == 'c')
        {

        }
        if(menuoption == 'q')
        {
            printf("Exiting Measurment tool 2.0\n");
            break; 
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: i have updated the code. So i have read the comments of your question and there you have explained a little better what you are trying to accomplish. So since you have the requirement to press 'q' to stop reading values. I have to read all measurments as string and convert to integer if it is not the character q.

Edit 2: Thanks to @user3629249 to point out some of the flaws from the code ill update with his suggestions.

Comment: I have fixed all the problems but i have another problem. I changed my while loop to

Comment: while (menuoption != 'q')

Comment: but when i enter e it doesnt use my functions to scan in values it simply prints out measurment tool bla bla

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", &input);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In this case, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using `%s' andor '%[...]'  always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%c", &menuoption);`  the format string "%c" should be: " %c" so any left over white space, like a newline, will be consumed

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Measurment tool 2.0\n");
        printf("v (View)\n");
        printf("e (Enter)\n");
        printf("c (Compute)\n");
        printf("r (Reset)\n");
        printf("q (Quit)\n");`  the function `printf()` is very expensive in CPU cycles.  Suggest: `printf("Measurment tool 2.0\n"
         "v (View)\n"
         "e (Enter)\n"
         "c (Compute)\n"
         "r (Reset)\n"
         "q (Quit)\n");  I would also suggest using the function: `tolower()` on the scanned character

Comment: OT: the posted answer contains the 'magic' number 10.  'magic numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `#define` or `enum` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name then using that meaningful name throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", &input);`  this statement will cause the compiler to output a message.  This is because in C, a 'bear' array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array.  So this statement  is trying to obtain the address of the address.  Strongly suggest removing the '&'